# Stackoverflow like javascript links for up/down voting

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to have javascript links that are not able to be followed by search engine bots (by not setting the href)?

For example: I currently use the following to show upvote and down vote links:

```
<a href="question-xyz/vote?type=up" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Upvote</a>
<a href="question-xyz/vote?type=down" data-method="post" data-remote="true"rel="nofollow">Upvote</a>
```

How can I write these links like stackoverflow's voting

Comment: The easiest way is to not make a link with `question-xyz/vote?type=up`. Use JavaScript to send a request to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery .click() method to send an ajax request that will upvote.

It would look like that :

HTML

```
<a class="voteButton" data-href="question-xyz/vote?type=down" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow"> Upvote </a>
```

Javascript

```
$('.voteButton').click(function(){

     $.ajax($(this).attr("data-href"), {
         [your ajax request object] 
     });

});
```

It is also possible to simply redirect the page with this :

```
.click(function(){
  window.href = $(this).attr("data-href") ;    
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to make use of the `data-remote = true` here? Which is Rails' unobtrusive js (it automatically makes clicking the link an ajax call).

Comment: Sorry I don't know Rails so I can't help you much on this one. But I am pretty sure it is not possible since the js function that makes the link an ajax call automatically probably depends on the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event listener to the links and use the preventDefault method, then you grab the data and make an ajax request.

By the way, I'd suggest to use buttons instead.

PD: SO doesn't put the href in the links, you should put only the *data-* attributes.

Comment: Is that possible using the `data-remote = true` magic of rails? (which automatically does the request as ajax when you click that link).

Comment: I don't know that way, but *any* way that use AJAX and prevent the link following should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a simple post binding to the vote buttons, with the url as a data attribute like so:

```
$('.upvote-btn').click(function(){
  $.post(
    $(this).data('url'),
    {type: 'up'}
  );
})
```